# Turned off the emulator and attempted to rerun it but got an error message

Tags: javascript, java, c#, android, android-studio

In the beginning I ran my code without a problem, but then after I turned off the emulator and tried to rerun it, it gave me this message:

```
Installation failed with message device 'emulator-5554' not found.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

What should I do? Please help.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the app in your emulator?

Comment: No， but installing the app isnt the problem. The problem is that I can't reopen the emulator, because whenever I try that it will show me that message. I have to quit and restart android studio in order to put emulator back to work.